# MATLAB SVMstruct

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm

I have a question about the SVMstruct function in MATLAB. Keeping in mind that I am a beginner to this sort of thing, could someone help me out with this :

For my project, I have downloaded the NUS-wide dataset of images, that also have a 500-D bag of words from here : http://lms.comp.nus.edu.sg/research/NUS-WIDE.htm  (Im assuming that all the image's BoW information is smushed into that one file). Now Im supposed to classify this using the SVM classifier. Am I correct in assuming that for the SVMstruct function : SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training,Group), I can give the entire BoW matrix as input (as the Training parameter), and then for Group I can give a character matrix of the tags(as the group parameter)?  Is  it ok if Training and Group have a different number of rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

The size of Training should be (N, M) where N (rows) is the number of instances (looks like 269,648 for this dataset), and M is the number of features (500).
The size of the Group array should be (N, 1) where each row corresponds to a training instance.

I don't think you can use a character matrix of tags for the group parameter. You might be able to give a cell array of strings like {'tag1'; 'tag2'; 'tag3'; ... 'tagN'}. Usually I would convert this to a numeric array.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Oh so is it like for each image in the Flickr database, there is ONE 500-D bag of words?  And also, how is the 'tag1', 'tag2','tag3' different from a character matrix? Is it because it has an order to it...? And a numeric vector would have only the numbers in order is that right? Sorry for the barrage of questions and thanks again!

Comment: I think "500-D bag of words" normally means there are 500 words, and for each word you will have a 0 or 1, based on whether that word is associated with the image. So each column in the training data matrix corresponds to a word. The value at (n, m) in the training data tells you "Is word m associated with image n?"

Comment: The example I gave was a cell array, rather than a matrix. So when you do `size(Group)` the result should be (N, 1) - if it was a character matrix, then the number of columns would be the length of the longest group name. The value at (n, 1) in Group tells you the ground truth label of the image which corresponds to the row (n, :) in the training data.